# How to make my render loop

Tags: animation, loop

I made an animation with 120 frames, 360 rotation and I want it to loop. It's a project with images as planes background and one spinning front object I want to loop but I don't understand how.  I have rendered it and I want to upload it to Open Sea, but how can I have the file to be in a constant loop?

I want to learn how to do it myself and not upload it to a gif maker.

I'm new to blender and appreciate all the help I can get :)

Comment: The loop is created automaticall by a player who is capable of repeatedly playing a file without a pause between the end of one turn and beginning the next turn. If you made an animation which last frame fits seamlessly to the first frame, this should work. Apart from that, I know nothing about OpenSea and have no idea what file formats are accepted there. Generally you can render an animation in Blender as an image sequence or a video file. For your 360° to be seamless, the 0° key should be on frame 1, the 360° key on frame 121. Or frame 0 and frame 120, and interpolation set to _Linear_.

Comment: although i hate to say it....but...it doesn't have to be linear. That it looks seamless the slope and the value of the curve should be the same on 0 and 120 as Gordon said...

Comment: i think 0 and 120 or 1 and 121 should be ok...or am i missing something!? i mean like this: it's seamless too...although it's not linear: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxgtf.png

Comment: @RobinBetts: i don't get your comment....but please enlighten me....

Comment: @Chris I can't.. you're right :) Misread.

Comment: Thanks guys I changed the frame to 121 but how do I make it loop if I want to post it somewhere? I want the animation to continue playing when I upload it somewhere else, like social media etc. Thanks

Comment: "normally" if you make an animation it will be looped by the provider where you upload it e.g. if you play an animation on instagram, Instagram repeats playing it from the beginning. You don't have to do anything for it. TikTok does the same. But youtube doesn't do that.